# sybase_fetch_array can't grab multiple rows

Tags: php, sybase

I want to grab 5 records from a sybase database. I am using [`sybase_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sybase-fetch-array.php)

```
$link = sybase_connect('192.168.1.29', 'dba', 'password')
                or die("Could not connect !");
$result = sybase_query("SELECT TOP 5 * FROM User");
$value = sybase_fetch_array($result);
```

I can run the sql through Interactive SQL and it works, but when I `var_dump($value)` the result is just one row. I have already tried:

```
while ($value=  sybase_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $value['UserID'];
}
```

which doesn't work either.

Comment: What output do you get from the var_dump of `$value`?

Comment: Definitely seems odd. the while should be working... it is normal that your first example returns just one row though. the doc for sybase_fetch_array clearly states it returns an array containing a single row, and that subsequent calls will return the next row if any

Comment: Have you tried sybase_fetch_assoc ?

Answer (score 0):

$value is a simple array.  If you looked at the PHP tutorials you will see that the way to index into the array is by offset, not hash field name.  For example, I am printing out the table row's field values into a table layout where field names are event_id (0), event_name (1), event_time (2), sc_id (3), etc.:

```
while($row = sybase_fetch_array($result)) {
    $i++;

    print "    <tr>\n";
    print "      <td class="A">$row[0]</td>\n";
    print "      <td>$row[1]</td>\n";
    print "      <td>$row[2]</td>\n";
    print "      <td>$row[3]</td>\n";
    print "      <td class="tmsgWidth tmsg">$row[4]</td>\n";
    print "    </tr>\n";
    print "\n";
}
```